# istream >> ostream << Operator Overloading with * Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, istream, ostream

How would I overload the >> and << operators if they are dealing with pointers?

in header:

```
friend std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, Classname* & e);
friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const Classname * e);
```

in cpp:

```
std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const Classname * e)
{   // what do I do here?
return outs;
}
std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, Classname* & e){
// what do I do here?
    return ins;
}
```

Comment: well, what you do depends on what you want to read/write from `Classname`. You access the variables through the `->` operator, other than that I am not sure what you're after. for instance: `outs << e->variable;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what is in the class `Classname`. If for example you have:

```
class Classname {
//...
private:
  int a;
};
```

.. then you might do:

```
std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const Classname * e)
{  
  outs << e->a;
  return outs;
}
std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, Classname* & e){
    ins >> e->a;
    return ins;
}
```

The idea being that the `<<` and `>>` operators ideally should mirror each other - so for example you can make use of them for serializing and deserializing your instances.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. Had tried this but now realized it crashed because i passed a null. I need some help understanding it though. What exactly does `Classname* & e` mean? I think `const Classname * e` means e is a pointer to a const Classname...

Comment: The second is a 'reference to a pointer' - so you could actually modify 'e' and see the effect on the variable you passed in.