# Returning a pointer to class function

Tags: c++, pointers, return

I need to return a pointer to a class function that's used to print out one of the data members within that class. I must traverse through a linked list to find the node with the name that matches the name the user searches for. I am not allowed to modify the parameters of the `find` function, and I'm not allowed to modify the way the name is outputted.

Here is the function that finds the name the user inputs:

```
Winery * const List::find(const char * const name) const
{
    Node     *traverse;

    traverse = headByName;
    while (traverse)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, traverse->item.getName()) == 0)
            return &(traverse->item.getName());               //getName just returns the name of the item
        else
            traverse = traverse->nextByName;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the call within `main`:

```
//I'm not allowed to change ANY of this
cout << endl << ">>> search for \"Gallo\"" << endl << endl;
wPtr = wineries->find("Gallo");
if (wPtr != 0)
    cout << wPtr;
else
    cout << "not found" << endl;
```

What I have written will not compile. I cannot find a way to write it so that it compiles AND actually outputs the name of the function.

EDIT: Here is the header file for Winery:

```
// make NO CHANGES to this file

#pragma once                // include this .h file file only once

#include <ostream>

class Winery
{
public:

    Winery(const char * const name, const char * const location, const int acres, const int rating);
    virtual ~Winery(void);

    // nothing needed in the .cpp file for these functions - complete implementation is provided
    const char * const getName() const { return name; }
    const char * const getLocation() const { return location; }
    const int getAcres() const { return acres; }
    const int getRating() const { return rating; }

    // print out column headings for lists of wineries, as specified by lab1output.txt
    static void displayColumnHeadings(std::ostream& out);

    // print out a winery, as specified by lab1output.txt
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Winery *w);

private:
    char    *name;
    char    *location;
    int     acres;
    int     rating;
};
```

Here is the definition of wPtr:

```
Winery  *wPtr;
```

2nd EDIT: Here is the overloaded `<<` operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Winery *w)
{
    out << left << setw(25) << *w->getName() << " " << setw(18) << *w->getLocation() << " " << setw(5) << w->getAcres() << " " << setw(6) << w->getRating() << endl;

    return out;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning a pointer to a function, you're returning a pointer to a `Winery` object. What are you expecting it to print out?

Comment: I need it to print out the `name` contained within the `Winery item`. I don't have access to `name` except through the function `item.getName()`.

Comment: You should declare the function to return `char*`, not `Winery*`. Aren't you getting an error because of the type mismatch in the `return` statement?

Comment: I would guess you actually want to `return traverse->item;` and also write an operator<<() for the Winery object. It's hard to tell without the definitions of Winery and wPtr.

Comment: @fileoffset - I will update the OP, but I think you're right.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105635/istream-ostream-operator-overloading-with-pointer for how to overload `<<` for a pointer to `Winery`.

Comment: You already have the `<<` overloading. You just need to fix the `return` statement to match the function declaration.

Comment: Almost got it... I've finished the overload, but now it just outputs the first character in the name. I'll update the OP to show the overloaded `<<` operator.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it! Everything works perfectly now. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Be warned that this mixing of C and C++ (using `char*` instead of `std::string`) indicates a very low-quality course.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Yeah, there has been a few people telling me this. My professor hates C++, so he's forcing us to use C stuff whenever he can. I'm not too happy about it.

Comment: Remove the * from '*w->getName()'