# Overloading ostream << operator with pointer as parameter resulting with memory adress on output

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I have some trouble with overloading ostream operator. There are 3 classes, abstract base class Packet another abstract class Sequence which inherits from Packet and class TimeHistory which inherits from Sequence.

```
class Packet
{
//some stuff
};

template <typename T = double>
class Sequence : public Packet
{
std::vector<T> buffer;
//some other stuff
}

template <typename T = double>
class TimeHistory : public Sequence<T>
{
template <typename X>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Packet *A);
//another stuff
}
```

And a friend function to print data in the objects

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Packet *A)
{
    TimeHistory<T> *th = dynamic_cast<TimeHistory<T> *>(A);
    out << th->device
        << th->description
        << th->channelNr;
    for (auto in : th->buffer)
        out << in << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

When I make an instance of the class like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Packet> channel1 = std::make_unique<TimeHistory<double>>(/*some constructor stuff*/);
```

and call the function

```
  std::cout<<(channel1.get());
```

I get only a memory cell adress at the output: 0x560c8e4f1eb0
Could someone point what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @churill even if I accept a pointer as an argument? I get a
no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << Packet
tried something like here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105635/istream-ostream-operator-overloading-with-pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::unique_ptr::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will return a pointer to the managed object. If you want to get a reference to managed value use

```
std::cout<< *channel1;
```

To overload `operator<<` for an abstract class you can use a reference instead of a pointer:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Packet &A);
```

Comment: no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << Packet

Comment: Which is not surprising, because you have not defined such an overload. The compiler does not magically know how to print your class.

Comment: yes but I cannot put (..., Packet A) in argument list because it's abstract

Comment: That's what references are for, see updated answer :)